# Azure Services Networking Protocols

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am drawing network architecture for my solution based on Azure. One of the ask is to list the network protocols used for inter-resource communication (e.g. Azure Storage to Data Factory). I tried to get a comprehensive view in Azure documentation but couldn't reach to get what I wanted.

May I take your help to understand the network protocols used in the following scenarios?

1. Azure VNET to VNET
2. Communication between Azure PaaS services (since PaaS services are web pages, are they by default use HTTPS)?
3. Azure VM to PaaS service like Azure SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure VNET to VNET

•   When communication between two virtual networks happen in Azure, the network protocols used in this scenario depend on the type of resources deployed in it, i.e., hosted in that virtual network. By default, only **TCP, UDP and ICMP TCP/IP protocols** are allowed within the virtual networks for communication purposes. ***DHCP via unicast (over UDP port 68 and 67) and UDP source port 65330, Multicast, Broadcast, IP-in-IP encapsulated packets and Generic Routing Encapsulation (GRE) packets are blocked within VNETs***.

> Communication between Azure PaaS services (since PaaS services are web pages, are they by default use HTTPS)?

•   Communication between Azure PaaS services also depends on the type of communication that happen between them through the underlying resources and services that they offer. Also, mostly the communication between Azure PaaS services is **TCP HTTPS protected by TLS 1.2 encryption level security certificates** ensuring the security of the communication channel and protected by default Microsoft FQDN for the services.

> Azure VM to PaaS service like Azure SQL

•   The communication protocol between the Azure VM and Azure SQL is purely over **TCP/IP over a specified and dedicated port for SQL transactions like 1433**.

Comment: thanks @kartik.. it helps !! Like SQL, is there a dedicated port for Storage account (blob and adls)? Is it via https between VM and Storage ?

Comment: When we create a file share in the storage account and map it on an Azure VM as a network file share, at that time, TCP/IP protocol is used over SMB port 445 to access the data in the file share. Similarly, when a blob storage is accessed through Azure data explorer using the SAS URI or any access key in other resources like a web application, the connection is over the internet itself on HTTPS port 443 since we are accessing the concerned resource through the Azure assigned FQDN for the storage account, hence TCP/IP protocol is used.